# Zend framework routing params

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller-router

I have several routes defined in my application.
When route A is matched and I assemble an URL using route B without resetting, it does not include the current request parameters.

Is there an easy way to include all the request parameters when assembling an URL via a different route than the current route? 
I did have a look at Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite->useRequestParametersAsGlobal, but this will (obviously) also include the request parameters when reset = true

Comment: Are you using `url` helper? If yes, please show code how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.

```
$oldParams = $this->_getAllParamas();
unset($oldParams['module']);
unset($oldParams['controller']);
unset($oldParams['action']);
```

Pass

```
array_merge(array('new'=>'param'),$oldParams)
```

to your URL view helper.